# How can I solve: Cannot retrieve length of file, path = 'WindowFilePath/FileName.jpg'

Tags: flutter, dart

First of all, the question is: can I transfer a file to an android application using the windows path?
Title Description:
I need to map an image to each product, I'm trying to do this as follows:

```
child: Image(image: FileImage(File('C:/Users/egore/Desktop/KR/Shop/server/static/${product.image}')))
```

Where product.image is a file name like ba27a066-101e-4e36-bc80-04b870373464.jpg

But I get the error described in the title(it didn't fit completely here's the continuation)

(OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

I added the following line to AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But I still keep getting the error.

What Im doing wrong?

Comment: Add it to the assets and load it that way.

Comment: @RichardHeap i can not add it to assets for some reasons

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access Windows file on Flutter Android App while debugging that way. However you can use plugin like [quick_usb](https://pub.dev/packages/quick_usb) to make a transfer file app.